# Best Firestore data model for file tree data

Tags: database, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, nosql, data-modeling

I'm currently building an app that needs to store data with a similar structure as a file tree. It looks something like this:

```
{
  "type": "folder",
  "name": "folder A",
  "private": false,
  "updatedAt": 1231243,
  "items": [
     {
      "type": "folder",
      "name": "subfolder A",
      "private": false,
      "updatedAt": 1231243,
      "items": [
         {
           "type": "file",
           "name": "file1"
         }
       ] 
     },
     {
       "type": "file",
       "name": "file2"
     }
   ]
}
```

What I'm aware so far, there are 3 ways of implementing this.

1. Just dump all the data in 1 doc
2. Create a subcollection for each items array
3. Create a flat folder structure and save the parent folder id for lookup

I'm looking for a way to get all of this data with as minimum query as possible, the ideal use case would be only having the root folder id and getting all the subfolder & items. But I'm not sure if that's possible.

Also, I'm planning to subscribe to the data in the future, so the file tree will be updated in real-time.

Please give me a suggestion on what should the data model looks like

**Update 1**
To give more clarification about the query that I will need:

1. I will only need to get the topmost folder (folder A) in this example and the items under it
2. I won't need to get the nested items directly
   example: getting Subfolder A / File 2 without accessing Folder A

Comment: You should first define exactly what your queries are going to be.  Without knowing how the data is going to be queried, you could make a bad decision about how to structure the data.  NoSQL databases like Firestore don't necessarily have the most flexibly querying like you get with SQL, so it's important to know up front what you want to accomplish.

Comment: Hi, @DougStevenson thanks for the tip! I've updated the post with my query needs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If all you need is to get the entire structure by some unique ID, just put it all in one document, and `get()` it using the known ID.  You have a 1MB [limit](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/quotas#collections_documents_and_fields) per document.

It can get more complicated if you need to access items within lists (which is not really possible to do without reading the entire document), so this would actually be a bad idea for that case.

You would also want to reconsider this if you intend to update the elements of this document frequently, as there is a [limit](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/quotas#writes_and_transactions) of 1 write per second (sustained).  You would want to split it up otherwise.

Comment: This only works when the total structure is always less than 20 layers deep right? Because firestore has a limit a a depth of 20 https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/quotas#limits